# Battery ran out while installing Visual Studio 2013, and installation continued automatically after restart?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, battery, visual-studio-2013

I thought I had enough battery, but it did run out completely (not hibernation or sleep, forced power off). When I plugged in my laptop and turned it on, Visual Studio 2013 Professional seemed to open automatically and just continue installing. Does this mean it's okay and nothing is corrupted? Does it detect that there was an interruption and fix it automatically? It wasn't very clear and I just want to make sure I don't run into any problems in the future.

Comment: How far were you in the instillation?

Comment: I was about halfway or two thirds. I'm not sure, because the installer was minimized while I was doing other things and the power ran out.

Comment: Well because you don't really know anything specific besides the fact that it wasn't done, the only way to answer this would be to use it until you find an issue.

Comment: Well, do you know if there is a feature that can do this? I'm really just wondering if it can automatically detect problems and fix them during the installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not came across any warnings/error during the installation, then there is no issues with VS installation. if you are still not satisfied with VS installation then you can go for the repair option available with the VS. Also check ActivityLog.xml for any errors

Comment: Also look in your %temp% folder (Start... run.. %temp%.. ok) and look at the *.log files there for errors.